# Does granite become soft as modelling clay at 2000 °C?

Tags: melting-point

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granite) tells us, it consists of $\ce{Al2O3}$ ($14.42\%$) (alumina) whose [melting point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide) is $\pu{2072^\circ C}$, and $\ce{SiO2}$ ($72.04\%$) (silica) whose [melting point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide) is $\pu{1713^\circ C}$. So does it soften to modelling clay (or at least partially soft, modelable via tools structure) at $\sim\pu{2000^\circ C}$, or does it stay hard and why?

Comment: There is no granite as a compound; it's chemical composition deviates quite a lot, and so do the thermal properties. This reminds me of the average hospital temperature of 36.6 °C (averaged from the patients with fever, 40 °C, and morgue, 4 °C)

Comment: Granite at this temp. is magma, not exactly modelling stuff...

Comment: One of the reasons why granite looks the way it does (some large crystals of feldspars embedded in a matrix of smaller crystals of quartz or mica) is because the *components* of granite don't crystallise at the same temperatures. Also granite is formed by slow cooling deep in the earth not fast cooling on the surface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mixtures of different compounds do not usually work like that.  They generally melt at lower temperatures than the constituent pure compounds.  So I would expect your granite to be not like modeling clay, but molten even before getting to the melting point of silica.

Relevant:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutectic_system.

If you want modeling clay, try 1300 °C where the Earth's lithosphere gives way to the asthenosphere.  See the Characteristics section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asthenosphere.

Answer (score 4):

Granite is not composed of the oxides listed, they are just a way of expressing the weight percentage of elements in the sample. Granite (and other rocks) are actually composed of minerals.

All granites contain quartz + alkali feldspar + plagioclase feldspar. Biotite is also pretty common and a variety of other minerals can also be less commonly present.

[image]

This is a phase diagram of the quartz - alkali feldspar - plagioclase feldspar system at 5 kbar pressure. The first melt forms in this system at the eutectic point at around 650 °C, but complete melting would not occur until a much higher temperature. I expect the last thing to melt would be left over quartz although it would first transform to tridymite and then cristobalite before melting finally melting.

Comment: So... when it gets to be "soft" so that one could model with it like with clay (*having tools that do not melt at that temp)?

Comment: @Blender Rocks never get that soft. They melt before they get to that stage.